# Different target directory for import library building with SCons

Tags: build, scons

I build my shared library:

```
env.SharedLibrary(target,Split(sources))
```

Documentation says
"On Windows systems, the SharedLibrary builder method will always build an import (.lib) library in addition to the shared (.dll) library, adding a .lib library with the same basename". That is right but I need another directory for it, so my question:

Is it possible to set another target directory for import library?
I want .dll and .lib in different directories:

```
bin/target.dll
lib/target.lib
```

It is possible to do it in VS projects but I also need a decision for Scons.
Thanks.

UPD:
We have the following structure

```
/project
       /bin
       /lib
       /include
       /source
           SConstruct
           /library
             lib.cpp
             SConscript

           /app
              SConscript
              main.cpp
```

app depends on library.
The following scripts are very simplified.
**SConstruct**

```
g_env = Environment()
...
g_target = 'Library_' + g_arch
if g_debug: g_target += 'd'
SConscript('library/SConscript')
SConscript('app/SConscript')
```

**library/SConscript**

```
sources = [ .. ]
env_lib = g_env.Clone()
...
env_lib.SharedLibrary('#../lib/' + g_target,sources)
```

**app/SConscript**

```
sources = [ .. ]
app_env = g_env.Clone()
app_env.Append(LIBPATH = Split('#../lib'))
app_env.Append(LIBS = Split(g_target))
app_env.Program('app',sources)
```

If I go to `app` dir and run

```
scons -u
```

I get all I need:

```
lib/Library.dll
lib/Library.lib
source/app/app.exe
```

But if I want just to rebuild Library running
`scons -u`
from `library` directory - just builds me .obj files, there is no final shared library.
I have no idea why it works so, I'm not quite familiar with it. But now we need to get final libraries in different directories (.lib in lib, .dll in bin) as I mentioned above.

Comment: If do this via VS projects, what does it do? Is there  a different command line option specified to the linker? Or does VS then copy/move the generated file after it's built?

Comment: @bdbaddog I've tried to add cmd line option /implib:path/lib/Library.lib like VS does. But  SCons rewrites this option - in output I see my option and the next Scons' one with default target directory - /implib:/path/bin/Library.lib

Comment: How did you try to add that to the command line?

Comment: @bdbaddog `env.Append(LINKFLAGS = '/implib:/path/bin/Library.lib')` before building library `env.SharedLibrary()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way of doing this, would be to use the `Install()` method (see chap 11 "Installing files in other directories" of our [UserGuide](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html)):

```
Install('lib','bin/target.lib')
```

Comment: May I use Install('../lib','target.lib')

Comment: sorry, not finished.. It seems ../ path doesn't work for Install. Or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Please also take into account #2 of our "most frequently-asked" [FAQs](http://scons.org/faq.html). As default SCons expects to be at the top-level of *all* your folder hierarchy, containing the directories that you install to. If it still doesn't work, please provide an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: please take a look at my updates in first post, I add projects structure and some parts of our Sconsripts.

Comment: Thanks, but this is still not an MVCE...and you don't show how you've tried to use `Install()`. Like this, it's not possible for me to tell you what you're doing wrong...because I don't see what you're actually doing. ;)

Comment: I think I've found out the right way to use Intall(). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should set no_import_lib in your call to SharedLibrary()

```
env_lib.SharedLibrary('#../lib/' + g_target,sources,no_import_lib=True)
```

Also, are you outputing a .exp file?

Answer (score 0):

Just list the name of the lib in the list of target files.

```py
env.SharedLibrary([target, 'lib/anyname.lib'], Split(sources))
```

SCons will recognize the target .lib file based on its suffix (`LIBSUFFIX`), and it will adapt the `/IMPLIB` argument of the linker automatically.